# Issue with caption inside measuredfigure environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, threeparttable

I need to write the figure sources under the figure themselves. As recommended in StackExchange, I used the *caption* package that I also used for the title of the figure, which comes over the figure. Because I did not want the source listed or numbered anywhere, I used *\caption*{}*.

I also wanted both the title and the source caption left aligned with the figure, meaning not starting from the begin of the line, but rather from the corner of the figure. To solve this problem, StackExchange recommended using package *threeparttable* and to put my figure in the *measuredfigure* environment.

Problem is, the asterisk in *\caption*{}* for the source does not work inside the *measuredfigure* as it is supposed to. How can I get rid of numeration/list *Figure 0.1* written in my source caption?

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\captionsetup{
  font=normalsize,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  format=hang,
  labelsep=space
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering%
    \begin{measuredfigure}%
    \caption{Transmission system}%
    \label{fig:Driveline}%
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{Driveline}%
    \caption*{\footnotesize\textbf{Source}: Author}%%
    \end{measuredfigure}%
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF generated from MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use a minipage instead of the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\captionsetup{
  font=normalsize,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  format=hang,
  labelsep=space
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
    \caption{Transmission system}%
    \label{fig:Driveline}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \caption*{\footnotesize\textbf{Source}: Author}%%
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be simpler to use the `copyrightbox` ppackage:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage{graphicx} % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{caption, copyrightbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
\footnotesize
\rmfamily
}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\captionsetup{
  font=normalsize,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  format=hang,
  labelsep=space
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering%
    \begin{measuredfigure}%
    \caption{Transmission system}%
    \label{fig:Driveline}%
    \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{lafemme100tetes}}%
   {\textbf{Source}: MaxErnst}%%
    \end{measuredfigure}%
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help again. I have formulate an answer, and I have a negative vote. Now I have banned my Mathematics. Can you help me, please? The question is combinatorial calculus. Can you see? +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I'd love to  help, but where is the question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607487/how-many-numbers-consist-of-four-digits-whose-sum-is-7

Comment: @Sebastiano: It is simpler to solve general problem: finding the  number of solutions in non-negative integers of the equation: $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n= r$$. One proves by induction this number of solutions is the binomial coefficient $\;\biggl(\dfra{n+r-1}{r}\biggr)$.

Comment: Can you solve my problem and upvote my question? Now I can't ask any question.

Comment: I've  upvoted and asked for reopening. There are really some noisome people on this site! My previous comment gives the general formula, but you need to prove an identity with the binomial coefficients (which I found only on the French site ‘Coefficient binomial’). For your exact problem, there results the answer is binom(10)(7), which is equal to 120, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Can you add an answer into my question? On hold is very ugly. Please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71838/discussion-between-bernard-and-sebastiano).